# FlexSlider affected

Tags: flexslider

When i use two flexslider instance manual control of second flexslider affect first slider

```
enter code here
this.contentTabs.each((index: number, element: Element) => {
            var slider: JQuery = $(element);
            $('.flexslider', element).flexslider({
                animation: "fade",
                overflow: "hidden",
                    slideshow: false,
                    smoothHeight: true,
                    directionNav: false,
                    selector: '.content > .panel',
                    controlscontainer: ".flexslider",
                    manualControls: " .tabs >.tab",
                })
```

;

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: I implement two same slider on one page container are same i using each for every slider but second  manual control  conrol first slider noy secod

Answer (score 0):

Are both sliders using the same class? Then it makes sense that the controls react to both sliders. If you want them to not interfere with each other use a different class for each individual slider. (".flexslider1", ".flexslider2" for example.)